# VPN user account looked again and again

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2016, user-accounts

i have issue in my Active Directory involvement there is issue with VPN user

1. user use network drive for document sharing in my Org
2. i reset user password many time but account looked after 5-15 second

   i know somewhere in my PC store old password but how can i find
   and is there any solutions to sync new password to AD

Answer (score 0):

Log-off the user or shutdown its PC.

Reset user password again, but check the the 'unlock account' box.

Make sure the user's PC is connected to the network so it can correctly access the AD.

Log-on the user with the new password. If the network is working, it should sync correctly to the AD.

Comment: user using point to site VPN not site to site how password sync                                      if we connect VPN we need to login PC